# VS Code: How to arrange project with access to OS source?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working an embedded system. VS Code can find function definitions no problem when I click on a header file in my code. But I would also like to be able to jump the source code for that definition. This requires making the whole OS tree accessible (which I have the source for).
Should I just add the OS tree as "Add Folder to Workspace...". I think that's the right answer?
The problem I have now is that as I look at the source code, it cannot seem to locate header files in *those* source code files. I add the include dirs to the c_cpp_properties.json but it still does not seem to find them.
Let me if, in general, I am not taking the right approach altogether ...

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question:
Edit the workspace configuration:

```
View>Command Palette...>C/C++:Edit Configurations (UI)
```

At bottom of window, expand "Advanced Settings" if it isn't already.
Add all the paths to source and includes to the "Browse: path" box. This 
Now pressings F12 in your working code should go to the definition function, etc.

This seems to *almost* work perfectly. Include files that are not in the includePath settings of the Configuration, *sometimes* are underlined with squiggles, *however* you can still press F12 on that include file and it will go to it. Then when you go back to previous file, the squiggles are gone. They do seem to re-appear at some point. Anyway, it works well overall.